# How to run a service running in a container in systemd, including systemd-notify and logging

Tags: docker, containers, systemd

We currently have a number of different services running on a host, and we are using systemd extensively, including systemd-notify for message passing and an own front-end for service management.

We would like to start running these services inside a container, to simplify dependency management and running multiple versions alongside each-other for testing. We want:

- systemd-notify
- Logging to both systemd journal and syslog
- Start and stop services with systemctl start / stop.

Please note; Most questions are about running systemd inside a docker container. That is *not* what this question is about. Instead, I want to run a (docker?) container inside systemd.

Answer (score 6):

We went with the following solution:

#### Podman

We decided to go with [Podman](https://dev.to/dev0x0/podman-the-docker-alternative-377f). Podman is a wrapper around RunC, with the CLI tools tuned to be a drop-in replacement for Docker. However, because it's not running the containers under a daemon (which I like a bit better anyway), hardly any plumbing is required to make systemd-notify work.

Just specifying `Environment=NOTIFY_SOCKET=/run/systemd/notify` in the sytemd service file suffices.

See [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_atomic_host/7/html/managing_containers/running_containers_as_systemd_services_with_podman) as well.

#### systemd-notify

Full example:

I'm using the systemd-notify test-script from: https://github.com/bb4242/sdnotify

Dockerfile

```
FROM python

COPY test.py /

RUN pip install sdnotify
RUN chmod 755 /test.py

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/python", "test.py"]
CMD ["run"]

EXPOSE 8080
```

build.sh - Creates the Podman container, needs to be in the same folder as Dockerfile and test.py script.

```
#!/bin/bash
IMAGE_NAME=python-test
CONTAINER_NAME=python-test
sudo podman build . -t ${IMAGE_NAME}
sudo podman rm ${CONTAINER_NAME}
sudo podman create -e PYTHONUNBUFFERED=true -d --name=${CONTAINER_NAME} ${IMAGE_NAME}
```

notify-test.service

```
[Unit]
Description=A test service written in Python

[Service]
# Note: setting PYTHONUNBUFFERED is necessary to see the output of this service in the journal
# See https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUNBUFFERED
Environment=PYTHONUNBUFFERED=true
Environment=NOTIFY_SOCKET=/run/systemd/notify
SyslogIdentifier=notify-test
NotifyAccess=all

ExecStart=/usr/bin/podman start -a python-test
ExecStop=/usr/bin/podman stop python-test

# Note that we use Type=notify here since test.py will send "READY=1"
# when it's finished starting up
Type=notify

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

So first install podman, and put the test.py from the url above, Dockerfile, and build.sh in a separate folder. Run `./build.sh`.

Then take the .service file, and put it with other systemd service files in `/usr/lib/systemd/user`. Do `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`.

Now, the service can be started and stopped with `sudo systemctl start notify-test` and `sudo systemctl stop notify-test`.

#### Logging

systemd will by default automatically log whatever is written to stdout/stderr to both its own journal (accessible with `journalctl`), and to the syslog.

See: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html

> SyslogLevelPrefix=
> Takes a boolean argument. If true and
> StandardOutput= or StandardError= are set to journal or kmsg (or to
> the same settings in combination with +console), log lines written by
> the executed process that are prefixed with a log level will be
> processed with this log level set but the prefix removed. If set to
> false, the interpretation of these prefixes is disabled and the logged
> lines are passed on as-is. This only applies to log messages written
> to stdout or stderr. For details about this prefixing see
> sd-daemon(3). Defaults to true.

Two issues:

Problem: When using podman as `ExecStart=`, the log-source will by default be the name of the executable, which is 'podman'.

Solution: Use the `SyslogIdentifier=` to specify the name for logging, like in the .service file example above.

Problem: There won't be any difference between log-levels for log-lines.

Solution: Like described [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd-daemon.html#) in the systemd documentation, prepend the log-lines with <7> (for debug), <6> (for info), <4> (for warn) etc. to have systemd set the right log levels everywhere, including for syslog. Even get colors in the journalctl tool for free!